# Eclipse Prolog: How to make a program that solves boolean expressions (replace variables so that the expression is true)

Tags: prolog, boolean-expression

So, I have this program that (using TKEclipse) allows me to query boolean expressions and answers with "Yes" or "No", depending on if the statement is true:

```
:-op(450,yfx,and).
:-op(500,yfx,or).
:-op(500,yfx,nor).
:-op(450,yfx,nand).
:-op(500,yfx,xor).

:-op(400,fy,--).
:-op(600,xfx,==>).



--Arg1:-not(Arg1).
 
Arg1 ==> Arg2 :- --Arg1 or Arg2.

Arg1 and Arg2 :- Arg1, Arg2.

Arg1 or _Arg2 :- Arg1.
_Arg1 or Arg2 :-Arg2.

Arg1 xor Arg2 :- Arg1, --Arg2.
Arg1 xor Arg2 :- --Arg1, Arg2.

Arg1 nor Arg2 :- --(Arg1 or Arg2).
Arg1 nand Arg2 :- --(Arg1 and Arg2).


t. 
f:-!,fail.
```

For example:

```
Q:t and t 
A:Yes

Q:t and f
A:No
```

Now I want to make the program accept variables using the predicate "bool_solve(Expr)".
For example:

```
Q:bool_solve(X and t)
A:X = t
Yes
Q:bool_solve(X and Y)
A:X = t
Y = t
Yes
Q:bool_solve(X or Y)
A:X = t
Y = t
Yes
'more'
A:X = t
Y = f
Yes
'more'
A:X = f
Y = t
Yes
'more'
No
```

I know how to replace the variables with a specific value (like t) using this code:

```
bool_solve(Expr):-
    term_variables(Expr,Vars),
    findall(X,X=t, Vars).
```

term_variables is built-in and finds all the variables in an expression. I know how to unify with the result of the findall with the Expr variables, but I cannot evaluate the Expr. I tried calling it, but it does not work (failed instantiation).

**TL;DR: I want to replace the "Goal" (X=t) of the findall predicate so that it evaluates the Expr, replacing all the variables with t or f.**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of     `findall(X,X=t, Vars)`

you could use: `sentences(Vars)`, where the predicate `sentences/1` is defined such:

```
sentences([]).
sentences([t|T]):- sentences(T).
sentences([f|T]):- sentences(T).
```

The predicate `bool_solve/1` might be defined by

```
bool_solve(Expr):-
    term_variables(Expr,Vars),
    sentences(Vars),
    call(Expr).
```

An alternative is:

```
bool_solve(Expr):-
    term_variables(Expr,Vars),
    sentences(Vars),
    Expr.
```

In swi-Prolog, this seems to work:

```
?- bool_solve(X ==> Y), write(X), write(' '), write(Y), nl, fail.
t t
f t
f t
f f
false.

?- bool_solve(X and Y), write(X), write(' '), write(Y), nl, fail.
t t
false.

?- bool_solve(X or Y), write(X), write(' '), write(Y), nl, fail.
t t
t t
t f
f t
false.
```

I used this kind of question to make the output look similar to a truth table, so it is easier to check whether it is correct.

---

Edit:

To visualize what the predicate `sentences/1` does, you may use this predicate:

```
show_instantiations(Expr):-
    term_variables(Expr,Vars),
    sentences(Vars),
    write(Expr), nl.
```

Now you can ask questions like the following:

```
?- show_instantiations(--X).
--t
X = t ;
--f
X = f.

?- show_instantiations(--X and X).
--t and t
X = t ;
--f and f
X = f.

?- show_instantiations(--X and Y or X).
--t and t or t
X = Y, Y = t ;
--t and f or t
X = t,
Y = f ;
--f and t or f
X = f,
Y = t ;
--f and f or f
X = Y, Y = f.
```

You'll get a nicer output, of course, by asking questions like:

```
?- show_instantiations(--X and Y or X), fail.
--t and t or t
--t and f or t
--f and t or f
--f and f or f
false.

?- show_instantiations(X ==> Y), fail.
t==>t
t==>f
f==>t
f==>f
false.
```

Comment: So the idea here is that the sentences/1 predicate "replaces" the variables in the Vars list with t or f, depending on which one allows the call(Expr) to instantiate. (I am kind of new, please excuse the simplicity of the above)

Comment: no, the predicate sentences/1 just does the substitutions, it is oblivious to the whatever is done to them. It is backtracking within the predicate bool_solve that excludes substitutions for which the boolean expression is not true.

Comment: I have edited to make it more clear what's happening.

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted to say. I made one of my own, a little different, because I got the logic behind this. Thank you!